# Matching first char in string to digit or non-standard character

Tags: mysql, database

I need to allow users to browse a table, with >1 million entries, by the first letter in the title.

I want them to be able to browse by every letter from A-Z, 0-9 in a list together and all other characters together.

Since it's a big database and it is to be displayed on a website, I need it to be efficient. Regex does not use index, so that would be too slow.

Is this possible or will I have to rethink the design?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create links representing every letter and number. Clicking these links will provide the users with the results from the database that begin with the selected character.

```
SELECT title FROM table
WHERE LEFT(title,1) = ?Char
ORDER BY title ASC;
```

Consider paginating these result pages into appropriate chunks. MySQL will let you do this with `LIMIT`

This command will select the first 100 records from the desired character group:

```
SELECT title FROM table
WHERE LEFT(title,1) = ?Char
ORDER BY title ASC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

This command will select the second 100 records from the desired character group:

```
SELECT title FROM table
WHERE LEFT(title,1) = ?Char
ORDER BY title ASC
LIMIT 100, 100;
```

Per your comments, if you want to combine characters 0-9 *without* using regex, you will need to combine several `OR` statements:

```
SELECT title FROM table
WHERE (
    LEFT(title,1) = '0'
    OR LEFT(title,1) = '1'
    ...
    )
ORDER BY title ASC;
```

Comment: Wont 10 LEFT(title,1) = "*" be pretty slow? And what about titles beginning with other characters? Thanks :)

Comment: You mean to select specific non-numeric and non-alpha characters? If you know that you have a limited number of characters, you may still want to use several `OR` statements. Otherwise you might want to consider using `REGEXP` if your users aren't going to very frequently browse the results starting with such characters. You'll have to test the queries for speed.

Comment: Thinking about it, OR statements might actually work. Thank you, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there's an index on the "Title", you should be able to use a SQL like 

`select * 
from myTable 
where Title like 'A%'`

(or 'B%', 'C%'...)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had included in topic that I am already doing that for A-Z. But the problem is to get out 0-9 in one query and all title that do not begin with A-Z0-9 in one query.