# Numeric calculation from VARCHAR fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a (simplified) table of results:

```
id | Result1 | Result2 | Progress
---------------------------------
1  | 1b      | 3c      | NULL
2  | 2c      | 2a      | NULL
3  | 3c      | 2b      | NULL
4  | P3      | 2c      | NULL
5  | 2c      | A       | NULL
```

I would like to populate the Progress column based on the difference between the numeric part (always first character) of the Result1 and Result2 columns. If the first character of either result column isn't numeric the Progress column should be NULL.

So the results for the table above should be

```
3c - 1b = 2
2a - 2c = 0
2b - 3c = -1
2c - P3 = NULL
A - 2c = NULL
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL/SQL retrieve first 40 characters of a text field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080860/mysql-sql-retrieve-first-40-characters-of-a-text-field), [Matching first char in string to digit or non-standard character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761507/matching-first-char-in-string-to-digit-or-non-standard-character) or [MySQL Select Query - Get only first 10 characters of a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959166/mysql-select-query-get-only-first-10-characters-of-a-value).

Comment: [**See that working fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34e92/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who replied, the quick response here pointed me in the right direction - here's what I came up with:

```
UPDATE mytable SET Progress =
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(Result1 AS SIGNED) > 0 AND CAST(Result2 AS SIGNED) > 0
            THEN CAST(Result2 AS SIGNED) - CAST(Result1 AS SIGNED)
        ELSE NULL
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `CASE` AND `LEFT()`

```
SELECT *,
(CASE WHEN
LEFT(Result1 ,1) - LEFT(Result2 ,1) >=0 OR 
LEFT(Result1 ,1) - LEFT(Result2 ,1) <=0
THEN LEFT(Result1 ,1) - LEFT(Result2 ,1)
ELSE NULL END ) `result`
FROM table
```

**EDIT**

First check if first value is numeric or not then calculate

```
SELECT *,

(CASE WHEN

CONCAT('',LEFT(Result1 ,1) * 1)  =0 THEN NULL

WHEN CONCAT('',LEFT(Result2 ,1) * 1)  =0 THEN NULL

WHEN LEFT(Result2 ,1) - LEFT(Result1 ,1) >=0 OR 

LEFT(Result2 ,1) - LEFT(Result1 ,1) <=0

THEN LEFT(Result2 ,1) - LEFT(Result1 ,1)

ELSE NULL END ) `result`

FROM `progress`
```

[**LEFT(str,len)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

### [See working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34e92/2)

Comment: Thanks, doesn't quite do it as the difference between the two results columns may be 0 (see second example in my question).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
   SET Progress = IF(Result1 RLIKE '^[0-9]' AND Result2 RLIKE '^[0-9]', Cast(Result1 AS SIGNED) - Cast(Result2 AS SIGNED), NULL);
```

Comment: Um, this answer fails to address the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for rows like the fourth one in my table above - i.e. the first letter isn't an integer.

Comment: No problem, I edited it to account for non-numeric inputs; in this case, it will produce NULL for the third column.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name
set progress=if(left(Result2,1)regexp'[:alpha:]'=1,null,left(Result2,1))-if(left(Result1,1)regexp'[:alpha:]'=1,null,left(Result1,1)) ;
```